# UITextField delegate in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have custom cell prototype in my storyboard called `YesNoTableViewCell`. In that cell, I have `UITextField`.

I want to **have the delegate methods of `UITextField` in my custom cell class**.

Here is my code:

MyController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YesNoTableViewCell";
    YesNoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
      cell = [[YesNoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
  }
```

YesNoTableViewCell.m

```
@interface YesNoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *yesNoInput;

@end
```

YesNoTableViewCell.h

```
#import "YesNoTableViewCell.h"

@implementation YesNoTableViewCell

@synthesize yesNoInput = _yesNoInput;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
      _yesNoInput.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

But realized this never called:

> (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
>           reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

because of:

> YesNoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

never returns nil.

Is there any suggestion for this?

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint in the initWithStyle method it never reaches that method ? Does your TableView even show ? Does the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method gets called too? I recall if a tableView's height is 0 the delegate methods don't get called.

Comment: Yes everything get called except the custom class.. As I said on top of the post, actually I want to put UITextField delegate methods in that custom class.

Comment: Did you specify tableView.delegate = self and tableView.datasource = self ?

Comment: I connect both of them in Storyboard. Actually the problem is not about the data are not displayed but the initWithStyle in my custom class is never called.

Answer (score 0):

it never return cell nil as you implemented

```
if (cell == nil){
  cell = [[YesNoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

so just remove this code

Comment: Yes I know but how to properly ini the custom class then?

Comment: just use [self.yourcollectionView registernib:[UINib nibWithName:@"nibName" bundle:[NSBundle Mainbundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"]